# Can natural deduction prove it's own rules, as my logic book says? Is there a level confusion there?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm currently studying John Nolt's Outline of Logic ( Schaum's series).

According to the author, one can use natural deduction to prove some rules of natural deduction itself, for example the absorption rule ( chap. 4, Solved problem 4.33).

Example. Consider the following proof

```
    (1)  P --> Q              hypothesis ( For conditional proof) 

    (2) ~ P v Q               DF --> 

    (3) Q v ~ P               Commut. v 

    (4)  ~ ~ Q v ~ P          DN 

    (5) ~ Q -->  ~ P          Df -->
```

(6) (P --> Q) --> ( ~Q --> ~P)    Cond. Proof  (1 - 5)

What did I prove here : a **"rule"** ? or simply the  **"sentence"** :

(P--> Q) --> ( ~Q --> ~P)

Comment: That doesn't look like a natural deduction proof... but regardless, that you can prove *some* rules from others doesn't lead to any circularity. All it is saying is that some of the rules (of the particular presentation of which there are *many*) may be redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Natural Deduction consists of a set of **fundamental rules**, which are each independent, and justified by the semantics of the connectives.   The fundamental rules can be used to prove sentences which may be used to justify **derived rules**.   Sometimes these sentences may be called Tautological Consequences (TautCon).

Here is the Natural Deduction proof for $\vdash (p\to q)\to(\lnot q\to\lnot p)$ using only the usual fundamental rules.  (Note: in most Natural Deduction systems, *implication equivalence* is *not* actually considered a fundamental rule.)

$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l} #1 \\ \hline #2 \end{array}}
\fitch{}
{\fitch{1.~p\to q\hspace{14.75ex}\text{Assumption}}
{\fitch{2.~\lnot q\hspace{14.5ex}\text{Assumption}}
{\fitch{3.~p\hspace{12.5ex}\text{Assumption}}
{4.~q\hspace{12.5ex}\text{1,3,Conditional Elimination}
\\5.~\bot\hspace{11.75ex}\text{2,4,Negation Elimination}}
\\6.~\lnot p\hspace{14.25ex}3{-}5,\text{Negation Introduction}}
\\7.~\lnot q\to\lnot p\hspace{11.5ex}2{-}6,\text{Conditional Introduction}}
\\8.~(p\to q)\to(\lnot q\to\lnot p)\hspace{2ex}1{-}7,\text{Conditional Introduction}}$$

Now, because this **sentence** is provable, we don't need to repeat all the above typesetting to apply conditional elimination.   We can just cite such a proof to justify deriving $(\lnot \psi\to\lnot \phi)$ from $(\phi\to\psi)$.   We can call doing this applying a **derived** rule of inference and, in this case, name it *Contraposition* .